# Using numeric only increment_id for orders? READ THIS! Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order, index, increment-id

There's a bug in MySQL which disabled searching by index if two columns are compared which are of a different type. Magento stores increment_id as VARCHAR in sales_flat_order but Magento does not cast to string when doing queries on that table. If you have a lot of orders you will start to notice that a simple select * query by increment_id can take exceptionally long.

MySQL query with int value:

```
time mysql -e "SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order WHERE increment_id=202405845"
real    0m30.788s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s
```

The explain of said query:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: sales_flat_order
type: ALL
possible_keys: UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID,IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 2236262
Extra: Using where
```

Now the query with a string value:

```
time mysql -e "SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order WHERE increment_id='202405845'"
real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Yes, that's a 29.94 second difference for this shop! They have 2.2 million records in the orders table.

The explain of the query with string value:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: sales_flat_order
type: const
possible_keys: UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID,IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID
key: UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID
key_len: 153
ref: const
rows: 1
Extra:
```

I managed to track down the best place to solve this:

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php

```
/**
 * Retrieve select object for load object data
 *
 * @param string $field
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object
 * @return Zend_Db_Select
 */
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    // START: Gracious Numeric IncrementId fix
    $fields = $this->_getReadAdapter()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
    if(isset($fields[$field]['DATA_TYPE']))   {
        $value  = $this->_getReadAdapter()->prepareColumnValue($fields[$field], $value);
    }
    // END: Gracious Numeric IncrementId fix
    $field  = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteIdentifier(sprintf('%s.%s', $this->getMainTable(), $field));
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->where($field . '=?', $value);
    return $select;
}
```

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php

```
/**
 * Check is order increment id use in sales/order table
 *
 * @param string $orderIncrementId
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isOrderIncrementIdUsed($orderIncrementId)
{
    // START: Gracious Numeric IncrementId fix
    $fields = $this->_getReadAdapter()->describeTable($this->getTable('sales/order'));
    if(isset($fields['increment_id']['DATA_TYPE'])) {
        $orderIncrementId  = $this->_getReadAdapter()->prepareColumnValue($fields['increment_id'], $orderIncrementId);
    }
    // END: Gracious Numeric IncrementId fix
    $adapter   = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $bind      = array(':increment_id' => $orderIncrementId);
    $select    = $adapter->select();
    $select->from($this->getTable('sales/order'), 'entity_id')
        ->where('increment_id = :increment_id');
    $entity_id = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
    if ($entity_id > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

As you can see I used functionality already built into Magento. The prepareColumnValue is used extensively during inserts but has been forgotten/skipped in the select portion of Magento.

It doesn't seem to be possible to override the abstract class so you're going to have to copy that to your local folder. I'm not sure about the resource file, you could give it a shot. I've just copied that to local as well.

Quick commands to make the right directories and copy the files there:

```
mkdir -p app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource
mkdir -p app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db
cp app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db
cp app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource
```

You'll have to make the edits yourself though, I never feel like it's safe just downloading someone's edits to core files from github myself so I figure I'm not the only one. If downloading modified core files from github doesn't scare you, it really should.

References:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/08/why-index-could-refuse-to-work/

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83857

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/381

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/383

I need to make a new pull request for the quote resource.

Thanks go out to everyone at OpenMage who helped me with this and pointed me in the right direction for a proper fix.

I am deeply humbled having had a pull request accepted by [Colin Mollenhour](https://github.com/colinmollenhour) himself, respect.

Comment: I think it's better to ask a question and answer it by yourself at one time.

Comment: I just felt it necessary to inform the community about this bug in core Magento. What better place than Stackoverflow? Nobody reads Magento forums and there's no official Magento 1 github repo. Plus stackoverflow gets indexed really well by search engines. If someone else is searching for this problem they will now find it easily.